# Simple way of creating jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I wanted to create a simple static jQuery based slider. Right now I just have the design. It has small dots as pagination in the right bottom, with a heading, an image and some content. It should be able to loop infinitely and also should have the ability to play and pause. Not much features are required.

Comment: To the one who gave a vote to close, I just shared my experience for a very restricted use case, as per [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Hope it is not a problem? And yeah, I am expecting other thoughts and answers too! :)

Comment: Yeah okay @Mat. I just thought of creating an own stuff. That's it.

Comment: Why do you need the way of *infinite loop* in the question? That should be in the answer right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I tried a content slider, with fixed pagination. I implemented this for something, which I would say after it is released. I could have simply used a plug-in, but due to some technical issues, and I too wanted to learn something, so I did it on my onw.

I started with the HTML Markup, starting with two `UL`s. One holds the *pagination* and the other, *content for the slides*.

Starting with this **HTML Markup**, I moved on to the **CSS** and *positioned* the layout elements.

#### HTML

```
<ul class="content-pagination">
    <li><a href="0"></a></li>
    <li><a href="1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="4"></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="content-slides">
    <li>
        <img src="slides/background1.png" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s!.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="slides/background2.png" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Heading 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s!.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="slides/background3.png" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s!.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="slides/background4.png" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Heading 4</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s!.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="slides/background5.png" alt="" />
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Heading 5</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s!.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I had somewhat a hard time fixing the issues caused by our ancient **Internet Explorer 7** and slightly modern **Internet Explorer 8** browsers, so I had to meddle with their proprietary form of *hacking* and fixed them! The **final CSS** came this way:

#### CSS

```
.slider {padding: 0; height: 150px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 270px;}
.slider .content-slides {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.slider .content-slides li {width: 270px; height: 150px; position: relative; float: left; list-style: none;}
.slider .content-slides li img {width: 270px; height: 150px; display: block;}
.slider .content-slides li .desc {position: absolute; font-size: 90%; background: #999; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 0 5px;}
.slider .content-slides li .desc * {color: #fff; width: 200px; margin: 5px 10px; line-height: 1.1em;}
.slider .content-pagination {text-align: right; position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 5;}
.slider .content-pagination li {float: none; display: inline; font-size: 0.75em; padding: 0.25em;}
.slider .content-pagination li a {width: 7px; height: 7px; border-radius: 7px; background-color: #ccc; overflow: hidden; line-height: 10px; font-size: 1px; text-indent: -999em; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;}
.slider .content-pagination li.active-marker a,
.slider .content-pagination li a:hover {background-color: #08c; color: #fff;}
```

And yeah, the width and height of *background* images are fixed and they were `270px × 150px`.

Now comes the really interesting part, which took me about an hour! The **JavaScript** rocks in consuming time like anything! :) I have to admit that I took a kind of low quality approach in my JavaScript, as I was concerned only about this **5 Content** always **with pagination** and **not scalable** in future kind of a slider.

#### JavaScript

First of all, I had no idea how these sliders work, but I had a small idea that the `UL` will be having the width of sum of all the `LI`s, which it holds. So, that became the first statement:

```
$(".slider .content-slides").width($(".slider .content-slides").children().size() * $(".slider .content-slides").width());
```

I need a **counter** to hold the current page been requested. So I initialized a counter `index` and assigning it a value `0`. Many of you people missed this part!!! Add this too!

```
index = 0;
```

The next step is to create a **function**, which animates the whole slider. Yeah, I used **jQuery** to help me out! So, the function goes this way:

```
function slideStart()
{
    curPage = ((index) % $(".slider .content-slides").children().size()) + 1;
    $(".slider .content-slides").animate({
        "left": -($(".slider .content-slides li:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").position().left)
    });
    $(".slider .content-pagination li").removeClass("active-marker");
    $(".slider .content-pagination li:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").addClass("active-marker");
    index++;
}
```

Since I declared `index` as a global variable, I can access it at any time from anywhere. Its scope is valid through the scripts and inside functions. I initialized a variable for the current page as the **modulus** value of the *count* of `index` divided by the *number of children* inside slider.

The next comes the awesome `animate()` function, which jQuery provides. It is used to change the *CSS Properties* as given in a smooth transition instead of a drastic or sudden change. This function now moves (slides) the left position of the list container `UL` to fit the next `LI` element.

Then comes the pagination stuff. It adds the current slide using another awesome *CSS / jQuery Selector*, `:nth-child()`, which literally selects the nth child of the container. Once a slide is loaded, the corresponding `LI` will be marked as active by adding a class `active`.

Finally the value of `index` is incremented by 1 using the *traditional way*!

Coming to the next function, which is adding the `click` event to the pagination buttons. I thought this would be the complicated way, but I managed to do in a simple way by just setting the `index` value, clearing the old timer, and restarting the slider function.

```
$(".slider .content-pagination li a").click(function(){
    index = $(this).attr("href");
    clearInterval(islider);
    slideStart();
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
    return false;
});
```

I added a `return false;` at the end to prevent the link from following the URL of it, else it would open the URL from its `href` attribute. Now comes the final part and the important one. The initializer for the script. We just need to start the slider using the function `slideStart()` and let it run for a fixed interval, say *2.5 seconds*. Since it needs to be executed after the document is loaded, it is given inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slideStart();
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
});
```

#### Final JavaScript

```
$(".slider .content-slides").width($(".slider .content-slides").children().size() * $(".slider .content-slides").width());


function slideStart()
{
    curPage = ((index) % $(".slider .content-slides").children().size()) + 1;
    $(".slider .content-slides").animate({
        "left": -($(".slider .content-slides li:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").position().left)
    });
    $(".slider .content-pagination li").removeClass("active-marker");
    $(".slider .content-pagination li:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").addClass("active-marker");
    index++;
}


$(".slider .content-pagination li a").click(function(){
    index = $(this).attr("href");
    clearInterval(islider);
    slideStart();
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    index = 0;
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
});
```

#### Full Demo: http://jsbin.com/uhowak/2

Hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar this is the online demo of the provided so far: http://jsbin.com/amituk/1/edit

Comment: @PraveenKumar and how it does loop?

Comment: Using the `setInterval`. You see I have given something like `% 5`, which makes the `index` to go in the range of `0` through `4`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar the demo you provided does not give the time to see the first slide at all and it does **NOT** loop.

Comment: jsFiddle has some issues in getting it right.. Will share the code on a better place in sometime. :)

Comment: @Roko in your fiddle, you need to wrap up all the content inside `div.slider`.

Comment: @Roko the final is here: http://jsbin.com/uhowak/2 Please test it as you wish. You haven't followed all the things said. There's no `index` value defined in yours. Now please check this out as I will update the link in the answer too! And please, remove all the downvotes! Thanks! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar +1 for the edit (+demo), but still, when the page first loads - there's no active button, we need to wait till the first 'loop kick' to see it active. But nice demo anyway. Good job. (Still, The question could be more descriptive.) And BTW use: `islider = setInterval(slideStart, 2500);`