# jQuery simple Background slider loop

Tags: jquery, css, slider, background-image

I need a background image to be changed automatically or by clicking slider bullets. It needs to set timeout and autoplay on window.load. Here's my fiddle:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjdyyLd/)

```
   <div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="changeBG">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="changeBG">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="changeBG">3</a>
    </div>
<style>
    #container{
      background-image: url(http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/eiffel-tower-wallpaper-18_fRZLW4V.jpg);
      width:400px;
      height:300px;
    }
    a{color:#fff;}
</style>
<script>
    $('.changeBG').on('click', function() {
        $('#container').css('background-image', 'url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg)');
    })

    // image 3
    // http://www.lanlinglaurel.com/data/out/71/4541654-3d-hd-wallpaper.jpg
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way of creating jQuery Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233575/simple-way-of-creating-jquery-slider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout() Function like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#container').css('background-image', 'url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg)')
;}, 3000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srjdyyLd/1/

Comment: Thank you. But I need a loop. It changes the background only once.

Comment: It is a loop, but the image is always the same. You can test it if you put an alert("test"); inside the setInterval.

Comment: Yeah, programmatically it's a loop, visually it's not. I want bg images to be changed in every 3 second continuously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout(); function to achieve this.

Hope it helps.